# Bootstrap carousel slider as a row

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a bootstrap (3.3.7) carousel from scratch, similar to this one:
https://littleseabear.com

I have managed to get the code to call posts but currently it shows the slides as a grid. O

Can someone help me figure out why the row does not work as a carousel - the arrows do not work to move the slides acorss. It either shows 4 as a grid or 3 with the 4th missing.
I can't seem to get further than this.

my guess is because the "active" class doesn't change when   the prev or next buttons are pressed. If I put "item" class in the else statement, the slides disappear but the "item" class in the if statement breaks it out of the grid (as seen in image 1).

**Index.php**

```
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : $postCount = 1;  ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="firstcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-10 mxauto " role="listbox">
            
                
                 <?php   
                 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :   
                     $the_query->the_post(); 
                     $postCount++; 
               
    $active = $postCount++;            
                if ($postCount === 2){ ?>
        <div class="carousel carousel-item  col-md-4 "> 
               <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', ['class' => 'img-fluid mx-auto d-block active', 'title' => 'Feature image']); 
                  ?>
                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <?php the_title();
                  the_excerpt();?>
                    </div>
                       </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="carousel  carousel-item col-md-4"> 
               <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', ['class' => 'img-fluid mx-auto d-block ', 'title' => 'Feature image']); 
                ?>
                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <?php the_title();
                   the_excerpt();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
       <a class="left carousel-control" href="#firstcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> Previous</span>
                </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#firstcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> Next</span>
                </a>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inside">

         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="firstcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-10 mxauto " role="listbox">
            
                
                         <div class="carousel carousel-item  col-md-4 "> 
               <img width="1024" height="683" src="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CFA4B291-1FA2-4C3E-8EDF-B691C7903838-scaled.jpeg?fit=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block active wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" title="Feature image" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CFA4B291-1FA2-4C3E-8EDF-B691C7903838-scaled.jpeg?w=2560&amp;ssl=1 2560w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CFA4B291-1FA2-4C3E-8EDF-B691C7903838-scaled.jpeg?resize=300%2C200&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CFA4B291-1FA2-4C3E-8EDF-B691C7903838-scaled.jpeg?resize=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CFA4B291-1FA2-4C3E-8EDF-B691C7903838-scaled.jpeg?w=2320&amp;ssl=1 2320w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                 Welcome to my new blog!<p>Welcome to my blog. This is the space I will use to talk about everything and anything, not just the books I am working on, [&hellip;] <span class="read-more-link"><a class="read-more" href="https://testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/?p=273">Read More</a></span></p>
                    </div>
                       </div>
                   
                        <div class="carousel  carousel-item col-md-4"> 
               <img width="1024" height="683" src="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?fit=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block  wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" title="Feature image" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?w=2560&amp;ssl=1 2560w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?resize=300%2C200&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?resize=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?resize=768%2C513&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C963F171-FC14-4173-A539-511060AA9DED-scaled.jpeg?w=2320&amp;ssl=1 2320w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                   Hello world!<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>
                    </div>
      
                </div>
                           <div class="carousel  carousel-item col-md-4"> 
               <img width="1024" height="683" src="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?fit=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block  wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" title="Feature image" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?w=2560&amp;ssl=1 2560w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?resize=300%2C200&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?resize=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?resize=768%2C513&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/C54FB831-E6C5-4BEF-B4B5-9AB7A234AF2E-scaled.jpeg?w=2320&amp;ssl=1 2320w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                   3000<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed interdum sem justo, ac efficitur metus ultrices vitae. Curabitur convallis nulla sem, mattis consectetur diam pretium [&hellip;] <span class="read-more-link"><a class="read-more" href="https://testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/?p=556">Read More</a></span></p>
                    </div>
      
                </div>
                           <div class="carousel  carousel-item col-md-4"> 
               <img width="1024" height="683" src="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?fit=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block  wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" title="Feature image" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?w=2560&amp;ssl=1 2560w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?resize=300%2C200&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?resize=1024%2C683&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?resize=768%2C513&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i0.wp.com/testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/C72C5057-B5F8-460F-A9A1-5995A65A2B74-scaled.jpeg?w=2320&amp;ssl=1 2320w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                   Shannon&#8217;s blogging guide<p>Here are some tips to help you write your blog. It will include: WordPress editor; Meta-Data Blocks; Images; Header Analysis Jetpack &#8211; the green thing [&hellip;] <span class="read-more-link"><a class="read-more" href="https://testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/?p=452">Read More</a></span></p>
                    </div>
      
                </div>
                     
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#firstcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> Previous</span> </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#firstcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"> Next</span>
                </a>
           
                     
               
        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
     
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-inner .active,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
        margin-right: initial;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
/**
 * File scripts.js.
 *
 */
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    $(&quot;#firstcarousel&quot;).on( &#039;slide.bs.carousel&#039;, function (e) {

        /*

        CC 2.0 License Iatek LLC 2018
        Attribution required

        */

        let $e = $(e.relatedTarget);

        let idx = $e.index();
        console.log(&quot;IDX :  &quot; + idx);

        const itemsPerSlide = 8;
        let totalItems = $(&#039;.carousel-item&#039;).length;

        if ( idx &gt;= totalItems - ( itemsPerSlide - 1 ) ) {
            let it = itemsPerSlide - ( totalItems - idx );
            for (let i=0; i &lt; it; i++) {
                // append slides to end
                if ( e.direction == &quot;left&quot; ) {
                    $(&#039;.carousel-item&#039;).eq(i).appendTo(&#039;.carousel-inner&#039;);
                }
                else {
                    $(&#039;.carousel-item&#039;).eq(0).appendTo(&#039;.carousel-inner&#039;);
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

[image: issue - grid]
[image: issue if "if statement" has class, "item"]

[image: issue if "else statement" has class "item"]

Comment: Can anyone please help me get this into rows?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't necessarily help us. We don't need to see what's in your `functions.php`, since that's a WP thing and doesn't add anything to this question. Show us your rendered HTML instead of your `index.php` file - we need to see the output. It looks like you are using Bootstrap, which you don't mention. And, lastly, this may be the way it was pasted, but your `@media` query is missing its closing bracket (and the media query is not relevant to your question).

Comment: @disinfor "Show us your rendered HTML" - the only thing on the webpage would be what's on the index.php... is there a different way to show HTML? would that be what is seen in the inspector page?

I showed the code for the others as I wasn't sure if js was causing a problem and thought it might help if it was.

Comment: The rendered HTML is what you would see if you "view source" on your site - or the inspector is fine too. The PHP is fine to show, however, we would need to see what the PHP renders - since we don't want to copy and paste a bunch of code to recreate your loop. Basically, show us the HTML between and including your `container-fluid` element. Put your JS/CSS back into the question. That's important. Also, what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @disinfor done that, I am using 3.3.7

Comment: `<p><p>Here are some tips to ...` - you can not _nest_ paragraphs in HTML. `<p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>` should be just `<?php the_excerpt();?>`

Comment: @CBroe, I have fixed that. :)

Comment: @disinfor if it helps, I have just launched it so I can share https://testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/